# Custom annotation call outs

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mapkitannotation

I am trying to make the annotation call out box as it would have no colour and be completely transparent.

the code is the following:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class CustomPin: NSObject, MKAnnotation
{     
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?

    init(pinTitle: String, location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = pinTitle
        self.coordinate = location
    }
}

func setPin(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
{
    let pin = CustomPin(pinTitle:"" ,location: location)

    self.mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
    self.mapView.delegate = self
    print(location.latitude)
    print(location.longitude)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? 
{   
    let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customAnnotation")
    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "marker")
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true
    annotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = addressLabel

    return annotationView
}
```

The result is show like this:

[image: my app]

The desired result should be like this:

[image]

What is there to modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked a little and I don't think Apple has anything you can do directly to the callout appearance other than modifying left and right accessoryViews. I think you have to create your own custom callouts.

Check this out if you're trying to make your own Custom Callouts: https://github.com/robertmryan/CustomMapViewAnnotationCalloutSwift

You can also use this Cocoapod for custom callouts: https://github.com/okhanokbay/MapViewPlus